# how could I write a query to find items which contains at least 3 consecutive years data from the latest year?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have many samples in the database these samples were produced from different years with the same id. I want to get the ids which have 3 consecutive years data from latest year. For example, if for id 100, the latest date is in 2019-09-01. If there exists data in 2018 and 2017. This id is qualified. How could I get them? I am using psql.

```
    id    date
    1    2020-01-09
    1    2019-02-03
    1    2018-06-02
    2    2021-01-03
    2    2019-02-05
    2    2018-03-09
    3    2020-01-02
    3    2019-03-01
    4    2019-02-01
    4    2019-02-04
    4    2018-03-05
    5    2015-02-03
    6    2019-02-06
    6    2018-05-06
```

My desired result

```
id
1
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Do you have multiple rows for an id for one year, for instance?

Comment: As @GordonLinoff indicated, please provide samples.  And as also suggested, a good answer will require knowing what DB is being used (Oracle, MSSQL, ...).  At a high level, it looks like you'll need a JOIN (say J) a subquery.  But the syntax for date calculations is wildly different between different RDBMS (especially Oracle vs everyone else)

Comment: Latest 3 consecutive years are 2018, 2019 and 2020.

Comment: I am using psql database. I attached a data image in the question. For instance, in the database 598 is qualified, 595, 734 is not. There should not be gap between the latest year with the following 2 consecutive years.

Answer (score 0):

In a sub-select use the lag function to look back to prior row and again to look back 2 rows. Then extract the year from the date and the 2 rows from lag functions. Compere the extracted value as needed.

```
with test(id, tdate) as 
     (values (1, date '2020-01-09')
           , (1, date '2019-02-03')
           , (1, date '2018-06-02')
           , (2, date '2021-01-03')
           , (2, date '2019-02-05')
           , (2, date '2018-03-09')
           , (3, date '2020-01-02')
           , (3, date '2019-03-01')
           , (4, date '2019-02-01')
           , (4, date '2019-02-04')
           , (4, date '2018-03-05')
           , (5, date '2015-02-03')
           , (6, date '2019-02-06')
           , (6, date '2018-05-06')
           , (1, date '2021-01-22')       --- added example row
     ) 
select distinct id 
 from ( select id
             , tdate
             , lag(tdate,1) over(partition by id order by tdate)  back1
             , lag(tdate,2) over(partition by id order by tdate)  back2 
          from test 
      ) s 
where extract(year from tdate) - 1 = extract(year from back1)
  and extract(year from back1) - 1 = extract(year from back2);
```

Note: The query uses distinct to eliminate duplicate ids selection which would result form more than 3 consecutive years. To see this remove "distinct" and see results with line marked  "added example row".